# How to disable full screen on F in keyboard in ReactPlayer?

Tags: reactjs, fullscreen, react-player

The problem is that if I click to play a video, and write something in a neighboring component, and accidentally press the F key on the keyboard, then the video, which is in another component, goes into full screen mode. How can I fix this problem?

```
// ...
<ReactPlayer
     {...attrs}
     ref={playerRef}
     className={styles.video}
     playing={playerState.playing}
     volume={playerState.volume}
     onEnded={handleOnEnded}
     onProgress={handlePlayerProgress}
     config={getVideoConfig(autoPlay)}
/>
// ...
```

```
export const getVideoConfig = (autoPlay?: boolean): Config => {
  return {
    file: {
      attributes: {
        controls: false,
        autoPlay,
        controlsList: "nofullscreen",
      },
    },
  };
};
```

i try to set controls={false}, vimeoConfig={{ iframeParams: { fullscreen: 0 } }} and something like this that I found on the Internet, but it doesn’t help. I still enter text and when I click on f, the video in the adjacent component goes into full screen mode, but I don’t need this. I want to go to full screen mode only when clicking a button

```
<ButtonWithTooltip
            className={styles.fullScreenBtn}
            Svg={
              screenfull.isFullscreen
                ? videoControlItems.FullScreenButtonIcon
                : videoControlItems.DefaultedScreenButtonIcon
            }
            title={
              screenfull.isFullscreen
                ? videoControlItems.FullScreenButtonTitle
                : videoControlItems.DefaultedScreenButtonTitle
            }
            onClick={handleFullScreen}
/>
```